# the footer does not remain at the bottom

Tags: html, css, position, footer

i desgined a webshop with oscommerce. you can see [here](http://multimedia-freiburg.de/caravista/shop)

The footer to stick to the bottom, but not fixed. The css is

```
#footer_wrapper {
    /* position: absolute; */
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    margin: 0;
}
```

But, when i change position to "absolute" the footer jumping up over the content.

See the example for the [product-list](http://multimedia-freiburg.de/caravista/shop/index.php?cPath=22_26).

Whats wrong?

Comment: your given link is broken. Please check.

Comment: If you use `position: absolute`, give your content a `bottom:` and then the height of your footer.

Comment: the link is repair, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add position in `#bodyWrapper` `position: relative;` &  `padding-bottom` to your footer `height`

```
#bodyWrapper{
    padding-bottom: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
```

replace this css

```
#body {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: table;
height: 100%;
margin: 10px auto;
min-height: 700px;
position: relative;
width: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `position: absolute;` to work, the parent element of the `#footer_wrapper` should have `position: relative;`

Comment: the parent element has `position: relativ;`

Comment: This should be comment rather than answer as its not an answer but suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  
  Content!
      
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

This works for me. while setting height 100% to body, you have to set all the parent divs with the height of 100%.